# One column to multiple in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do I turn one column into multiple ones in a data set, using python? For example,

```
user_id   info_name    score
1         a            50%
1         b            75% 
1         c            100%
```

The goal is to switch the `"info_name"` column to be multiple columns so that the `"user_id"` is not duplicated 3 times, and information about a given user is all in one row, like this:

```
 user_id   a     b      c  
 1         50%   75%    100%
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`pd.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = df.pivot_table(index='user_id', columns='info_name',
                     values='score', aggfunc='first')\
        .rename_axis('', axis=1).reset_index()

print(res)

   user_id    a    b     c
0        1  50%  75%  100%
```